# По файлу в python 3.9

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть определенный текст и он записан в файл txt формата и представим что его название будет word. Мне нужно чтобы при активации программы, можно было по нажатию на любую клавишу клавиатуры, выводилось следующее слово.
И еще вопрос, удобно же будет взаимодействие клавиатуры и кода совершать с помощью библиотеки Pygame?

Comment: Если правильно понял нужно по 1 слову выводить содержимое `word.txt`? можно считать содержимое файла, разбить его по словам (split()) в список и далее через модуль 'keyboard' получать содержимое списка по 1 слову.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например можно сделать так:

```py
import keyboard

l = []
# Читаем файл и сохраняем список слов.
with open("word.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    l = f.read().split()

max_index = len(l) # сколько слов в списке
index = 0 

# Выводим слово равное текущему индексу и увеличиваем индекс на 1
def on_triggered(e):
    global index
    global max_index
    for _ in keyboard._pressed_events:
        if index < max_index:
            print(l[index])
            index += 1

# выводит новое слово по нажатию на клавишу
keyboard.hook(on_triggered)
print("Нажмите ESC для остановки")
keyboard.wait("esc")
```

Answer (score 1):

На файла формата `.txt` не знаю, лучше использовать формат `.py`, а из него импортировать переменную. Типа  в `word.py` будет `text = 'то что должно напечататься'`, а в `program.py` будет импортироваться переменная: `from word import text`.

А на счёт фиксации нажатия клавиш, лучше использовать библиотеку `keyboard`. Для установки открой терминал и напиши `pip install keyboard`, после в пайтон файле импортируй библиотеку при помощи `import keyboard`. Теперь тебе нужен цикл который будет проверять нажатие клавиши:

```
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('клавиша'):
        pass
        # код
    while keyboard.is_pressed('клавиша'): # Этот цикл нужен что бы код постоянно не повторялся
        pass
```

Так же нужно напечатать текст, для этого создадим функцию `enter`:

```
def enter(sentence:str):
    for letter in sentence:
        keyboard.press(letter) # нажатие клавиши
        keyboard.release(letter) # отпускание клавиши
```

Теперь нужно всё совместить, вот финальный код, файл `word`:

`word.py`:

```
text = 'твой текст'
```

`program.py`:

```
from word import text

def enter(sentence:str):
    for letter in enter:
        keyboard.press(letter) # нажатие клавиши
        keyboard.release(letter) # отпускание клавиши

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('клавиша'):
        enter(text)
    while keyboard.is_pressed('клавиша'): # Этот цикл нужен что бы код постоянно не повторялся
        pass
```

Но не забывай: при нажатии клавиши нажатая буква удалятся не будет, а если в `text` будет буква на которую ты назначил код, она может повлеять на программу

Comment: зачем вам строку хранить в отдельном файле .py это дикость как по мне. Да и вопрос не о том. Там надо было просто прочитать весь текст из  файл